# Intresting behaviour of IPAddress.TryParse

Tags: c#

I'm using IPAddress.TryParse to validate an IP address, but if I use

```
if (IPAddress.TryParse("192.168.1.009", out ip)
```

it fails, but

```
if (IPAddress.TryParse("192.168.1.007", out ip)
```

passes. Basically if the last digit is an 8 or 9 it fails on a valid IP address.

I'm not sure what to do to get this to work?

Comment: it is because your last part start with `0` so it will consider as octa numbers so value having 8 and 9 will fail

Answer (score 4):

Quick guess:

`009` and `007` are interpreted as octal numbers, whereas `007` is a valid number in base-8 and `009` is not.

Try `if (IPAddress.TryParse("192.168.1.9", out ip))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your last part is starting with `0` a quad starting with a zero must be treated as a base 8 (octal) number, hence for example any quad part starting with zero and containing the digits 8 or 9 is not valid. if u try "192.168.018.110"..this will also fail..See my comment below you question

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for change format:

```
IPAddress ip;
string ipString = "192.168.1.009";
string goodIpString = Regex.Replace(ipString, @"[0]+(\d+)", "$1");
var res = IPAddress.TryParse(goodIpString, out ip); // true
```

Comment: **Warning! The regex is wrong** and causes problems in several cases.
Example: `192.108.200.100` --> `192.18.20.10` . . . . . use this regex instead:
`Regex.Replace(ipString, @"\b0+(\d+)", "$1")` or look to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions to validate an IPv4 address string and parse it into an object of type `IPAddress`:

**1.)**

If you like **regular expressions**, you can cleanup leading zeros before `TryParse()` with only one single line of code.

```
string ipString = "192.168.1.009"; // any input

// strip leading zeros from IP address, because otherwise the digits 
// are interpreted as octal numbers with a wrong result or parser error!
// usage example: "192.108.064.008" --> "192.108.64.8"
string cleanedAddressStr = Regex.Replace(ipString, @"\b0+(\d+)", "$1");

if (IPAddress.TryParse(goodIpString, out IPAddress ipAddress))
{
    // do something with variable ipAddress
}
else
{
    // report error in address string
}
```

Side note: `\b` is the symbol for *word boundary*. In the regex above it matches the string start and the dots.

**2.)**

If you prefer a solution **without regex**, you can use this.

```
string ipString = "192.168.1.009"; // any input

IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.None;
try
{
    string[] splittedString = ipString.Split('.');
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];
    byteArray[0] = (byte)int.Parse(splittedString[0]);
    byteArray[1] = (byte)int.Parse(splittedString[1]);
    byteArray[2] = (byte)int.Parse(splittedString[2]);
    byteArray[3] = (byte)int.Parse(splittedString[3]);
    ipAddress = new IPAddress(byteArray);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // report error in address string
}

if (ipAddress != IPAddress.None)
{
    // do something with variable ipAddress
}
```